# Drawing on Canvas vs Drawing using OnRender

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls

I need to draw shapes using WPF. I have figured out two ways of doing this.
Method 1

```
protected override void OnRender(DrawingContext drawingContext)
    {
        base.OnRender(drawingContext);
        Rect rect = new Rect(new System.Windows.Point(50, 50), new System.Windows.Size(400, 100));
        drawingContext.DrawRectangle(System.Windows.Media.Brushes.Aqua, (System.Windows.Media.Pen) null, rect);
    }
```

Method2

```
    public void Draw()
    {
         DrawingVisual drawingVisual = new DrawingVisual();
         DrawingContext drawingContext = drawingVisual.RenderOpen();
         Rect rect = new Rect(new System.Windows.Point(50, 50), new System.Windows.Size(400, 100));
         drawingContext.DrawRectangle(System.Windows.Media.Brushes.Aqua, (System.Windows.Media.Pen) null, rect);
         drawingContext.Close();
         canvas.Children.Add(new VisualHost { Visual = drawingVisual });
    }
      public class VisualHost : UIElement
     {
         public Visual Visual { get; set; }
         protected override int VisualChildrenCount
         {get { return Visual != null ? 1 : 0; } }
         protected override Visual GetVisualChild(int index)
         {return Visual;}
     }
```

How are these different? Am able to draw and display using both methods.Since OnRender is an override provided, will it make more draws compared to my draw function? When should I use one over the another? Please guide. TIA

Comment: Are you asking for opinions? Because you don't give context in which we have to evaluate preferences. Visuals are useful if you need visual as an object (to do something, e.g. change or animate property). Otherwise blunt rendering (with caching) has better performance typically.

Comment: Yes, I wanted to know whats the better approach, my requirement is to draw on top of images displayed, and without animations or any such interactions.